# How do I resolve the "IAB TC string" warning in AdSense for EU users?

Tags: google-adsense, gdpr, eu-cookie-law

I recently saw a warning in my Adsense dashboard:

> We've detected an issue on your IAB TC string on one or more of your
> sites or apps. These errors may affect your ability to serve ads to
> European users. A detailed report is available for you on the EU user
> consent page.

When I open the "Learn More" page. I saw a lot of legal stuff and really don't quite understand 100% of them.

However, I know that I need to display a confirm box to my users to let them click "accept" or "decline", like many sites are doing now.

But there are many technical questions that are not answered by Google at all. For instance:

- How do Google or the EU authority know I have put the confirmation box?
- How do Google or the EU authority know that I follow the user's actual action?
- How do I detect a user's geolocation? By IP or? I don't have very strong ability in backend dev, can I do it purely by JavaScript?

Why not Adsense just put something like this:

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).takecareEUUsers();
```